# WebAPI Authentication with access token and refresh token

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, access-token, refresh-token

I have a ASP.NET MVC application using Forms Authentication against a custom database Users table.

I need to add a series of Web API controllers for a mobile app to interact with the web application.

For the authentication, i need to generate and access token and refresh token to return to the mobile app. How can I do that?

Can anyone point me in the right direction of tutorial resources for this? There are a lot of unclear ones i already found.

Comment: I recommend the tutorials of Taiseer Joudeh: http://bitoftech.net/2015/02/16/implement-oauth-json-web-tokens-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-and-identity-2/
and http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I found as well :)